# How to rotate an object to face the camera?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make an object face the camera by using arbitrary independent vector which is `new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)` and also using the camera position.

Here is the code block that I am using

```
let w = this.Camera.position.clone().normalize();
let b = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1); // arbitrary independent vector
let v = new THREE.Vector3().multiplyVectors(w, b).normalize();
let u = new THREE.Vector3().multiplyVectors(w, v);
let matrix = new THREE.Matrix3();
matrix.set(
   u.x, v.x, w.x,
   u.y, v.y, w.y,
   u.z, v.z, w.z
);

this.Point.position.applyMatrix3(matrix);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please guide me and Thanks!

Comment: What is happening instead? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No I am getting some random rotation matrix which I don't need. I want to have a matrix that is point to the camera position at anywhere